# Who created user in AIX/Unix?

Tags: unix, root, aix

Is there a way I can find out who created specific user(eg. username is testuser)?
when we use one of them

`lsuser -f username`

`lsuser -c username`

`finger username`

and these commands give information about normal attributes but there is no information about who created this user.

Normally, root only (or users with root privileges) can create users.

But is it getting stored somewhere?

If yes then where and how can we get it?

Also, assume that only root is creating the user, will there be an IP (or date-time information) stored for that from where someone created the user?

Comment: This should be asked at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find the creation date and time of a particular user.
Unix doesn't store the creation date of the file, but only the last modifies date.
If you have created a file in your user directory at the time of user creation and that file has not not been modified, then the date of the file could be the the creation date of the user.

Answer (score 0):

The following will not give an exact answer to what you are asking, however by using [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) the password file (along with other files in /etc) will be placed under version control. So then you will at least be able to find out which day that a user was added. Etckeeper is such a valuable tool, install it even if it does not match what you were looking for.